# finding characters and words in a strings without regex or nltk in python 3.5

Tags: python, string

The objective is to find characters or group of characters within an string.
for example`sample_input="this+is-a;{example--;{string}"`

i need to separately get: this,is,a,example and string.
That is if a group of characters appear together i want the group else if the occurrence is of an individual character then i need it.

Is it possible to do it without nltk or regex?

Kind of a solution is to give the inputs in a string and use `file.readlines()` to get the characters line wise and use `.isalpha()` method to check and get them... Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking. If you want to know if a specific substring is in a string you can just do: `if 'substring' in string:`

Comment: For example if "a" appears alone i want "a".

Comment: But if "alone" is in string i need alone without specifically searching for it

Comment: you can check if each char is alpha or not with `.isalpha()`

Comment: What attempts have you made so far to solve the problem? In general, to get a response on SO you'll need to show what you've done so far and show where the problem is. [Here is more info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking good questions

Comment: i am aware..but that .isalpha() doesn't help with the problem fully

Comment: Well i could only think of word_tokenize or regular expression checking hence the query

Comment: Why don't you want to use regular expressions? They're built in and very simple

Comment: Thank you for that method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do with regular expressions (the re library in python), but you asked for it without, so here's a method that can do it:

```
def split_on_nonalpha(s):
    cur_str = ''
    for c in s:
        if not c.isalpha():
            if len(cur_str) > 0:
                yield cur_str
                cur_str = ''
        else:
            cur_str += c
    if len(cur_str) > 0:
        yield cur_str
```

Using it, it will return a generator, which can be turned into a list or looped through:

```
sample_input="this+is-a;{example--;{string}"
list(split_on_nonalpha(sample_input))
```

['this', 'is', 'a', 'example', 'string']